# QuerySet() to Json Serializing

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-views

I have these Models: Ml, Mli and Mlvid. I grab information like the following

```
mliv = Mlvid.objects.filter(mli__ml__pipe_id=175083)
```

How do I sterilize something like this? I can serialize it like the following

```
 serdata = serializers.serialize("json", mliv)
```

but it only contains the Mlvid fields. How do I also add the fields for Ml and Mli that relates to the query? Thank you. If you need more information, please let me know.

I am thinking I need to iterate over mli  and build a list/ dict and then serialize the list or use the dict afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `mliv` contains objects. You could query for the fields you need and not the entire object:

```
mliv = Mlvid.objects.filter(mli__ml__pipe_id=175083).values('field_1', 'field_2')
```

Where `field_1` and `field_2` are `Mlvid`'s fields. You will get a list of dicts, serializables.

Comment: Ok, when doing the following:
    mliv = Mlvid.objects.filter(mli__ml__pipe_id=175083).values('mli__ml__street')

    serdata = serializers.serialize("json", mliv)

I get the following error
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

and if I use 

    response = JsonResponse(mliv)

I get the following error:

    TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects): `JsonResponse(mliv, safe=False)`

Comment: It throws up error. I found out that the values() needs to be iterated to return a dictionary.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values 


It states: Returns a ValuesQuerySet — a QuerySet subclass that returns dictionaries when used as an iterable

Getting ready to post a solution I have come up with so far.

Answer (score 0):

In order to serialize a queryset like the following and get all the related fields:

```
mliv = Mlvid.objects.filter(mli__ml__pipe_id=175083)
```

First I used values()
    mliv = Mlvid.objects.filter(mli__ml__pipe_id=175083).value('mli__ml__street')

Next I create a list

```
mlist=[]
```

Now I iterate through mliv and add the content to the list

```
for m in mliv:
    mlist.append(m)
```

Next, I pass the list to  JsonResponse()

```
resp = JsonResponse(mlist, safe=False)
```